# How to bind radiobuttonlist with jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have added `radiobuttonlist` into asp `updatepanel`, `radiobuttonlist` is  bound form table in codebehind with C#.But `updatepanel` gives error at `postback`.can anybody help me to bind `radiobuttonlist` with `Jquery` on `page load`.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdPanel_Questions" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">        
    <ContentTemplate>             
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Lbl_QuestionTitle" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" 
                Font-Size="Medium" Height="45px" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div> <p></p>      
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadBut_Answer" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="RadBut_Answer_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            CellSpacing="5" AutoPostBack="True" CellPadding="0">            
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>            
        <div class="SelectedAnsMsg alpha">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ID="Lbl_SelectedAnsMsg"></asp:Literal>
        </div>
        <div class="Butskipnext">
            <div class="Butskip">
            <asp:Button ID="But_Skip" runat="server" Text="Skip" SkinID="AltButton"  />      
            </div> 
         <div class="Butnext">
            <asp:Button ID="But_Next" runat="server" Text="Next" SkinID="Button" 
                 onclick="But_Next_Click"  />
        </div>                           
        </div>                                                  
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>

            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadBut_Answer" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I think you should first focus on solving that error instead of jumping into alternatives.

Comment: What error did you get? Also it might help to reveal your code-behind.

Comment: Kindly use PageLoad in javascript as you are using UpdatePanel

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use jQuery to bind RadioButtonList at Page_Load? If you want to bind RadioButtonList on Page_Load using jQuery, then it is something to do in Javascript (i.e. either in .aspx page or separate Javascript file), but not code behind.

I have not used jQuery, but the following code in code-behind works well to bind table data to RadioButtonList.

For the example purpose, I have Taken DEPT(DEPTNO, DNAME) table.

Now, I hope you can understand the code since it is very easy.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DEPTNO, DNAME FROM DEPT", objConn);
            objConn.Open();
            RadBut_Answer.DataSource = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
            RadBut_Answer.DataTextField = "DNAME";
            RadBut_Answer.DataValueField = "DEPTNO";
            RadBut_Answer.DataBind();
            objConn.Close();
        }
    }
```